# Separating Data into training and test

Tags: r

I've separated the data into training and test but it takes the full data and not the size I set it too - I set the size to 250 but still get the full near 900000

```
set.seed(321)       
SplitIndex <- sample(x = c("Train", "Test"),size = 250,replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75,0.25))

TrainData <- loanfilev2[SplitIndex == "Train", ]
TestData <- loanfilev2[SplitIndex == "Test", ]

table(TrainData$loan_status)
table(TestData$loan_status)

set.seed(27)

KnnModel <- train(form = loan_status ~., data = TrainData, method = 'knn')  
KnnModel

plot(KnnModel)
```

basically, I want TrainData to be about 150 observations but I am getting the full 900000 observations instead

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Please enter code as code, and not as images.

Comment: Can you please show a sample for your data? Please consider pasting your code in the question rather than a picture.

Comment: hopefully now it is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you want.

```
set.seed(321)  # set the seed to get reproducable results 
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(loanfilev2)), size = 150) # train data indices

trainData<- loanfilev2[train_index, ] # train dataset
testData <- loanfilev2[-train_index, ] # test dataset
```

You may also set the size in percentage of the data set

```
sample_size <- floor(0.10 * nrow(loanfilev2)) # or whatever percent you desire
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot sorry for the poor question and phrasing, I am not too great in this area but this really helped - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your solution hasn't worked is at least twofold: (1) incorrect subsetting index and (2) mask size not being equal to the number of records (i.e. rows) in the original dataframe (if you are trying to subset a dataframe using a mask smaller than the number of records, R will just recycle the mask).

In the call that creates a subset mask called `SplitIndex`, try replacing `c("Train", "Test")` with `c(TRUE, FALSE)`.

```
SplitIndex <- sample(x = c(TRUE, FALSE), size = nrow(loanfilev2), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75,0.25))
```

You will have a vector of size equal to the number of rows in your dataframe, populated with `TRUE` (75% of the vaues) and `FALSE` (25% of the values). This way, you won't even need to test for equality to strings `"Train"` or `"Test"`; you will simply produce a subset of the data where the rows match a `TRUE` value in the mask. Hence, the rest of the code becomes:

```
loanfilev2[SplitIndex, ] #Train
loanfilev2[!SplitIndex, ] #Test
```

Comment: no my issue is it wont adjust the test and train to size see how you have size = nrom(loanfilev2) i want to set that to a number that to a number for knn model